# VB6: Error -2147418113: Automation error Catastrophic failure

Tags: excel, vb6, office365, vba

I am using the `CreateObject()` in VB6 and I am getting an Automation Error whenever the code reaches the `CreateObject()` part. The error is not present when I open the application that I put on the `CreateObject()`. Any ideas? I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: If you are using Excel, this sounds like VBA - not VB6.  Please update the question to include as much of the code as is necessary to replicate the problem.  (Probably just the declaration of the object, and the `Set` statement, but maybe more if the problem doesn't exist when running just those two lines.)

Comment: Error -1234567: Crystal ball not found. Perhaps it might be useful to add the actual code that shows which object you are trying to create? Hit the [Edit] link to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you re-read your question, you've already answered it yourself.  It only works if the Excel application is already open.  You are probably trying to create/open a workbook or spreadsheet.  Instead of assuming that Excel is open, you would probably have to open Office 2016 itself as an object (I don't know what that code would be off the top of my head) and then you could create an Excel application from -that- object.